# Javascript scroll into selected category HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to make when i click a category to scroll into the destination/  example = category 1  = it must scroll to selected category projects

```
    $('.item-filter').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).data('filter');

    $(".item-filter a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $(".item").fadeTo("slow", 0.1);
     $(selector).fadeTo("slow", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Demo : [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/g9cg0jn3/2/)
Add below script on category then a page will be scrolled, if you want to scroll a list then you can also do.

JavaScript
   $("li[class*='-button']") in place you have to select category.

**JQUERY**

```
$("li[class*='-button']").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 3 }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Should i put ur code between mine ?
bcuz it doesnt work

Comment: Can u tell me how should i use the code to scroll to my selected category projects ??

Comment: First of all you have add click event on selected category. After that set scrolls based on select category optio.

Comment: You have to set on click event in category which is selected by you. After that you have to add scroll based on selected category.

Comment: Aha , how to make it ?  i have post my code can u edit it ?